# Hidden element with visible :after - CSS

Tags: html, css, checkbox, styling

I have recently created a way to style HTML checkboxes and radio buttons, but it requires adding additional elements to it, like a `<p>` or a `<span>`. This isn't terrible inconvenient, but when you're styling (CSS) a complete web software, having to go back and rewrite every checkbox can be annoying.

I recently just had a "revelation" about how to style them without using any additional elements, and it works amazingly in Chrome, but in Firefox, well, lets just say it doesn't work.

My HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" />
```

My CSS:

```
input[type="checkbox"]
{
    visibility:hidden;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:after
{
    visibility:visible;
    content:"W";
    display:block;
    background:#0ab9bf;
    width:20px;
    line-height:20px;
    text-align:center;
    height:20px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-indent:-100px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked:after
{
    text-indent:0;
}
```

I was hoping that someone here can help? Keep in mind that I am looking for a strictly CSS solution to this. I will seek a javascript solution only as a last resort. Until then, my hopes are high.

I guess my question is, what is preventing Firefox from showing the "checkbox?" And how can I fix this. Is there a different way to go about doing this?

Comment: The problem might be that you're, effectively, trying to show the child of an element that you've hidden. [Supporting demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/86maA/), using `opacity`.

Comment: I figured this to be the case, but Chrome seems to like it just fine. Firefox ends up displaying it as you would expect; nothing. I am hopeful though, lol

Comment: CSS solutions wont work cross browsers. `jQuery` or its plugins is the way to go.

Comment: Perhaps [this explains your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/css-after-pseudo-element-on-input-field)? It doesn't work in [FF nor IE10](http://jsfiddle.net/KV6Tv/1/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing it's as David Thomas suggests that the pseudo-element is not visible because of it's 'parent' element. The reason for it working in other browsers could be explained by a different implementation, where the pseudo-elements aren't considered children of the element maybe?

### Another method

Anyhow, I've had a bit of experience styling checkboxes and radio buttons like this. A pretty cool trick I've learnt is to hide the `<input>` off screen and style the associated `<label>` with some fancy selector tricks. This method leverages the fact that clicking on the `<label>` will also click the associated `<input>`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/PJsSA/1/)

#### HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check" />
<label for="check"></label>
```

#### CSS

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px;
    top:-9999px;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label {
    visibility:visible;
    content:"W";
    display:block;
    background:#0ab9bf;
    width:20px;
    line-height:20px;
    text-align:center;
    height:20px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
    background:#F00;
}
```

### Improving upon the method

This method uses the `a + b` selector which means select `b` which immediately follows `a`. So the `<label>` must come after the `<input>`. A 'safer' way to do this would be to wrap them in a container and style using the general sibling selector `a ~ b`. The styles will then tolerate the `<label>` in a different position provided they are still siblings.

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check" />
    <div>It will still work!</div>
    <label for="check"></label>
</div>
```

### Compatibility

Standalone this method is not compatible with IE8 and below because it doesn't support `:checked`. The usual way to get around this is to add a class `.checked`, but unfortunately IE8 also has a [rendering bug](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13783840/1156119) when changing classes and you need a little more hacky JavaScript.

```
var labels = document.querySelectorAll('label');
for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    labels[i].onclick = handleClick;
}

function handleClick () {
    var checkbox = document.getElementById(this.getAttribute('for'));
    // do something with checkbox.checked
    alert(checkbox.checked);
}
```

Luckily you shouldn't need to support anything lower than 8 due to its [now tiny market share](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201303-201303-bar) (< 0.77%).